# How do I check for data and stop code execution if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a table of links (5 total).

link1
link2
link3
link4
link5

The first 2 links are dynamic. Sometimes there is data for them and sometimes not.

The last 3 links are static and are always displayed.

The data for the dynamic links is deeply nested in the state.

example: `state.data.item.statics.footerLinks`

footerLinks is an array of objects:

`footerLinks [{name: "****",url: "****"},{name: "****",url: "****"}]`

I need to destructure the state.props object to get the footerLinks only if the footerLinks exist.

i.e. `const { footers } = state.data.item.footerLink;`

The problem is I also need to map footers after the check to change the "name" key to "link" if it exists. If it doesn't exist I need to immediately stop the code before the map because I cannot map null or undefined. It will throw an error. I can't figure out how to stop the code from reaching the map if there are no footerLinks and still giving me the 3 static links to show in the UI. This is what I have so far:

These are the static links that always exist:

`const mainlinks = [
{label: "*******", url: "********"},{label: "*******", url: "********"},{label: "*******", url: "********"}];`

**** Check for footer links ****

**** if footerLinks exist I want to assign to const footer.
if they don't exist I need to terminate the process so we don't reach the map ****

**** if footerLinks exist then map footers to change name to label ****

`const shopLinks = footers.map((footer) => (
return {label: footer.name, url: footer.url }
)`

`const allLinks = shopLinks.concat(mainLinks);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you sticking with map if do not fit your use case , use forEace instead of like below  ...

```
const { footers = [] } = state.data.item.footerLink;
let dynamicLinkHolder = []
const shopLinks = footers.forEach((footer) => (
 if(footer){
    dynamicLinkHolder.push({label: footer.name, url: footer.url })
  }
)
const allLinks = shopLinks.concat(dynamicLinkHolder);
```

Comment: But what if footerLinks data is empty? Then const footers = undefined. If so, you cannot map or forEach. You will get an error. I need a fail safe to return only the 3 static links if there is no footerLink data. If there is data in footerLinks then I need to map or forEach and change the key "name" to "label".

Comment: const { footers =[] } = state.data.item.footerLink;
 if you do like above you can easily skip the error...